# Use emacs(aquamacs) with python 3.2

Tags: emacs, python-3.x

The default python version on mac osx snow leopard is python 2.6.1. I am learning python 3, so I have to change the interpreter. I have changed the setting in preference, so that it points to `/Library/framework/python.framework/version/3.2/bin/python3.2`. I believe that is where my 3.2 interpreter is installed. 
When I restart Emacs, everything works fine. When I start the interpreter, it says python 3.2:

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88452, Feb 20 2011, 11:12:31) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

However, when I ask Emacs to execute a buffer, this message shows up:

```
execfile(r'/var/folders/yV/yVXYrzONGSaZeoBmB-mdkE+++TI/-Tmp-/python-2180L5f.py') # PYTHON-MODE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

I don't know how to fix it. It has nothing to do with my code though, because this message shows up even when I try to execute:

```
print ("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 does not have `execfile()`, so your emacs simply doesn't support Python 3.

Comment: Which emacs supports Python 3?

Comment: @Lili: You have to ask that at an emacs mailing list. Or maybe at superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is a longer answer, as I had to look into it.

1. Python 3 will need to be installed on your system.  I already installed HomeBrew, so this involved `$ brew install python3`.   You can install with other methods as well.
2. I use a virtualenv for Python 3.   I make a virtualenv by using the `virtualenv -P python3 myproj` Aquamacs lets you `M-x virtualenv-activate` to set it.
3. There were problems in the `python-mode.el` file, a lisp file hiding down in your `/Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/Resources/lisp/aquamacs/edit-modes/python-mode`.  [Andreas Roehler](https://code.launchpad.net/~a-roehler) patched the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1221310).  If the [main python-mode page](https://launchpad.net/python-mode/) is still on version 6.1.2, you download a new `python-mode.el` [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~python-mode-devs/python-mode/python-mode/view/head:/python-mode.el) and copy it over your existing version.

Now it should work.